# Asp.net MVC3 Membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

Hi i'm using membership in MVC 3 project to register an login users. But the project in production will use active directory provider for login. In AD we have some information like email and firstname where in the project we will have more information like photo, adress, phone etc ...

I want to know how to deal with that. I think i have the choice between use a custom membership provider or use a second table where i can put my additional data and join the membership and additional table with a foreign key.

What's the best solution ?

Comment: just a guess - as I haven't used it myself so far - but couldn't you use the Intranet-Application Template, that should include a membership provider that by default talks to an active directory... it should be possible to extend its userprofile to add photos and other additional data

Comment: You're right but i have found a lot of problems with the Intranet template so i used the Internet Template. It's possible to log user from AD even with the Internet Template. My question is what is the best work with custom provider or map 2 tables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Best way to implement a user specific details is `Profile` wich can be implemented directly by extending `ProfileBase` From `System.Web.Profile`.